# Is there any standard Binary search tree implementation in python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I want to use a binary search tree. I know that python has support for dictionaries. But it is a hashmap implementation. I want to know if python has any standard binary search tree implementation which I can import. If there is no standard implementation can someone suggest any well tested third party implementation for it. Also it must run on python 2.7.x

Comment: AFAIK, `set` is implemented as a binary search tree. That's what I would use

Comment: Are you talking about a self-balancing tree such as AVL or red-black trees?  If you're not dynamically adding and deleting from the tree, it's easy enough to do a binary search on an array without any third-party code.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I'm pretty sure `set` is a hash-map.  [CPython source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1b97cc71a05e/Objects/setobject.c)

Comment: A balanced tree like AVL would be great. But I need to add / delete dynamically :)

Comment: @SamMussmann: which version of python was that? I was talking about python2.6, but again, I could be wrong

Comment: @inspectorG4dget All of them, I think. :-)  I just went and looked at the source for 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, and 3.3 and they all use a hash-map.

Comment: I'm curious why you would prefer a binary search tree over hashmaps?  What do you expect to gain (ordering or prev/next searching perhaps) and what are you willing to trade-away (losing O(1) insertion and deletion for example)?

Comment: I want comparison operations over keys. Such operations can't be done using hashmaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest open source code for binary search tree, https://github.com/pmontu/BSTPython

Comment: I want a binary search TREE implementation. Thats the code for binary search :(

Comment: Added a link to binary search tree.

Comment: Sorry. I guess the author removed the repo. Please suggest!